# gamlss ploting smooth baseline hazard

Tags: r, survival-analysis

How do I get a plot of the "smooth" baseline hazard after fitting the discrete survival function below

```
burr<- function(xi) {
    linkfun <-function(mu) log(((1-mu)^(-xi)-1)/xi)
    linkinv <- function(eta) 1-(1+xi*exp(eta))^(-1/xi)
    mu.eta <- function(eta) exp(eta)*(1+xi*exp(eta))^(-1/xi-1) 
    valideta <- function(eta) TRUE
    link <- "burr"
    structure(list(linkfun = linkfun, linkinv = linkinv, mu.eta = mu.eta,
                   valideta = valideta, name = link), class = "link-gamlss") }

model00 <- gamlssNP(y ~ cs(FS$t,df=3)+v1+v2, 
             random=~1|id,family=BI(mu.link=burr(5)),  
             data=FS, K=1, mixture="gq", tol=0.5, 
             control = NP.control(EMcc=0.001, trace=FALSE), 
             g.control = gamlss.control(trace=FALSE))
```

Comment: Please could you share the output of `dput(FS)` or, at least, of `dput(FS[20,])` ?

Comment: It's unusual to see a column of the `data` argument accessed with `$` in the RHS. I also see no censoring mechanism. But I'm not a gamlss user. In any case you should be posting data or referencing an example data set in one of hte packages.